# what are the difference between SMTP and TCP handshaking?

Tags: networking, tcp, smtp

What are the differences between SMTP and TCP handshaking? Why is SMTP handshaking important?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here. This question makes absolutely no sense, either, as SMTP and TCP handshaking have no relation to each other. One has to do with email, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP handshake happens at the transport layer of the TCP/IP protocol stack, involving signaling using TCP flags, TCP sequence numbers, TCP port numbers and IP addresses.

SMTP handshaking occurs at the application layer of the TCP/IP protocol, above the transport layer.  SMTP handshaking is rarely called a handshake and is composed of the server sending a `220` message representing its banner, the client sending an `EHLO` or a `HELO` message along with its name, to which the server will respond with a `220` message indicating success.  Subsequent to this the actual email exchange begins.

You can read more about this in [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).